# How to use async fetch inside Vuex store in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this problem with Nuxt.js and Vuex store, I want to call an API from vuex module, It works if I navigate between pages, but for first-page load data renders only server and then I can't receive data into my page component using vuex getter, What i am doing wrongly?

in component

```js
   async fetch({store, params}){
       await store.dispatch('api/singleAuthors', params.id)
    }
```

api.js module

```js
export const state = () => ({
    singleAuthor:null,
})

export const mutations = {
    getSingleAuthor(state, payload) {
        state.singleAuthor = payload
    }
}

export const actions = {
    singleAuthors(vuexContext,payload) {
       this.$axios.$get(`/api/author/${payload}`)
       .then(response =>{
           vuexContext.commit('getSingleAuthor', response)
       })
    }
}

export const getters = {
    callSingleAuthor(state) {
        return state.singleAuthor
    }
}
```

Comment: So `this.$axios.$get(`/api/author/${payload}`)` is working inside of your vuex action when you navigate between the pages but not if you reach it directly by accessing by the URL? This should work properly. Sure you don't have anything else blocking? Because, `fetch()` is okay for this kind of behavior, only `asyncData()` cannot do that.

Comment: Yes, It's works when i navigate between page components, but when i am trying to access page directly from url vuex getter not works, but data is rendered inside server console :/

Comment: The issue is from somewhere else, not in the code that you've linked so far. Can you `console.log('stuff')` in your action, just before the axios call and try to figure out if nothing is blocking here?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The store is called accordingly. Only thing which helps is calling axios directly with `await this.$axios.get(...)` !Be careful, this only works if fetch() has no params. It has to stay `async fetch( )`. Does someone know why ?